# ¿cuales son los archivos de inicio de sesión en linux?

Tags: linux

en una guía el profesor nos pide mover los archivos de inicio de sesión hacia nintendo/supermario, cita textual. El no especifico cuales eran los archivos de inicio de sesión.

lo primero que hago es ejecutar como root usermod -d /nintendo/supermario mariobros

y luego muevo /home/mariobros hacia /nintendo/supermario.

quedando así la ruta /nintendo/supermario/mariobros/*los directorios del usuario.

pero cuando los muevo ya no puedo iniciar sesión con el usuario mariobros.

lo que me lleva a la pregunta ¿serán los archivos correctos?

o será que estoy del todo mal en lo que intento.

Comment: `/home/USUARIO` es la carpeta personal de los usuarios. Sin esta carpeta, no te podrás loggear con el usuario `mariobros`. Lo que estas haciendo es cambiar el nombre de la carpeta del usuario sin `/home`. Por este motivo no puedes iniciar sesión con este.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si lo que deseas hacer es cambiar el directorio `/home` de un usuario, puedes utilizar: `sudo usermod -d /nuevo/directorio -m nombredeusuario`